# Oracle how to count until current row

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume a table with a column with binary value, what I like to achieve is result here

```
--------------------
| data  |   result |
-------------------- 
| false |     0    |
| false |     0    |
| true  |     1    |
| false |     1    |
| false |     1    |
| true  |     2    |
| true  |     3    |
| false |     3    |
| false |     3    |
| true  |     4    |
.....
--------------------
```

reach row will in the result column is a count of total `true` value in the data column from top row till next row.

I checked on lag() or lead() function however here the parameter is very dynamic in this situation.

Comment: do you have a column to specify the ordering? also include your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a running sum.

```
select t.*,sum(case when data='true' then 1 else 0 end) over(order by specify_order_col) as result
from tbl t
```